# Can an Android phone be backed up while stuck at boot loop?

Tags: backup, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-note

I have Samsung Galaxy Note N-7000 which got stuck at boot loop after installing and opening and app called InstaFrame, is there anyway to backup the device before doing a factory reset to get the device working again? The device isn't rooted, thanks.

Comment: I'd say at least 95% no. How should that work? "Starting to ba... om, boot." → Try booting into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and remove that app. Then reboot. With a little luck, you don't need to factory-reset.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing a factory reset, I did not lose any photos though, how come?

Comment: They are stored on your SDCard usually (internal or external). Factory-reset usually leaves those alone, just cares for "device memory" (see our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) for more details).

Comment: Anytime! That's what this site is about, so feel welcome to ask more :)